# Select Option Value comparing giving the wrong result

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, html-select

Haven't seen a thing like this before... When comparing option values of two select boxes, it is sometimes giving the right result and sometimes giving the wrong one.

```
<select class="form-control" id="p_in_qty" style="width:100px; margin-left:50px;">
<?php
$array = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30);
              foreach ($array as $value) {
                       echo '<option value="'.$value.'">'.$value.'</option>';
                 }
?>
</select>
<select class="form-control" id="p_av_qty" style="width:100px; margin-left:50px;">
<?php
$array = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30);
foreach ($array as $value) {
    echo '<option value="'.$value.'">'.$value.'</option>';
}
?>
</select>
<button type="button"  onClick="check();" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">Check</button> 
function check(){    
         var i_qty = $('#p_in_qty').val();
         var s_qty = $('#p_av_qty').val();    
         if(s_qty > i_qty){           
        alert("s_qty is greater than i_qty") ;    
    }else{
       alert("fine");
      }    
  }
```

When I select "14" for the id `p_in_qty` and "8" for the id `p_av_qty`, it's giving the wrong result. This is occurring for some values in combination and for some it does not. This is a freakishly weird thing I have come across for the first time.!! What is going on here?

Comment: Can you post a fiddle of the rendered html instead of the PHP... also try to wrap in a parseFloat to make an integer for comparing... parseInt($('#p_in_qty').val(), 10);

Comment: Yeah I think Simon is right about parsing them - the string "8" is indeed greater than the string "14"

Comment: @SimonStaton I guess you meant `parseInt()`

Comment: Have put my comment into an answer

Comment: @SimonStaton  yeah it's working. well what is exactly parseInt() doing? Didn't know that before

Comment: Great, is it okay if you accept my answer \/ parseInt is converting your string value '1' into an integer 1... this means its evaluating this condition if(1>2) instead of if('1'>'2')

Comment: Its also worth noting that parseInt requires an *optional* second radix parameter... this tells the method how it should handle the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thought I would leave an answer although solved in my comment...

You need to convert the string value into an integer for comparing...
**http://jsfiddle.net/v47qdaap/**

```
check = function(){
    var i_qty = parseInt($('#p_in_qty').val(), 10);
    var s_qty = parseInt($('#p_av_qty').val(), 10);

    if(s_qty > i_qty){
        alert("s_qty is greater than i_qty") ;
    } else {
        alert("fine");
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you tell me what is the second parameter here? i.e., "10" ? What is it doing?

Answer (score 2):

It makes alphabetic comparison.
For comparing numbers you need to parse int

```
 var i_qty = parseInt($('#p_in_qty').val());
 var s_qty = parseInt($('#p_av_qty').val());
```